# Aws NACL rule ephemeral port range

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

I am facing an issue while configuring emporial port range in NACL outbound rule. I am connecting to ec2 instance from my local computer. If I give port range 49153–65535 in NACL outbound rule.
I am getting server time out issue. So that I changed the port range from 1024-65535 in NACL outbound rule. Now, I am able to connect. Can I know why port range 49153–65535 is not working ?.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is the default requirement , you can find more information in the official documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-network-acls.html#nacl-ephemeral-ports

Answer (score 0):

if a request comes into a web server in your VPC from a Windows 10 client on the internet, your network ACL must have an outbound rule to enable traffic destined for ports **49152**-65535.from https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-network-acls.html#nacl-ephemeral-ports